# Email obfuscator

Tags: javascript, email

Review this code for code quality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Email obfuscator</title>
<style>.email { unicode-bidi: bidi-override; direction: rtl; }</style>
<h1>Email obfuscator</h1>
<p>A kick-ass email obfuscator, inspired by <a href="http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/email-obfuscator#code">Mathias Bynens's <code>obfuscate_email()</code> PHP function</a>. This tool will encode (HTML) and/or reverse (CSS) any email address you enter, making it less vulnerable to spammers who use email harvesting software aka spambots.</p>
<h2>The output</h2>
<p id="preview">(preview will be shown here)</p>
<p><textarea id="output" rows="6" cols="60" onclick="this.select()"></textarea></p>
<h2>The input</h2>
<form name="OBFUSCATOR"> 
  <p><label for="email">Email: <small>(enter the email address to be obfuscated)</small></label> <input type="text" id="email" size="28" autofocus></p>
  <p><input id="encode" type="checkbox" checked> <label for="encode">Convert into HTML entities ("encode")</label></p>
  <p><input id="reverse" type="checkbox"> <label for="reverse">Reverse using CSS</label></p>
  <p><input id="link" type="checkbox"> <label for="link">Create HTML link</label></p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Obfuscate This!" onclick="obfuscate_email()"></p>
</form>
<script>
function obfuscate_email() {
  var email = document.OBFUSCATOR.email.value,
    encodedEmail = "",
    output = "";

  if (!email) {
    alert("Please enter an email address.");
  } else {
    if (document.OBFUSCATOR.reverse.checked) {
      email = email.split("").reverse().join("");
      output = "<span class=\"email\">";
    }
    if (document.OBFUSCATOR.encode.checked) {
      for (var i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
        encodedEmail += "&#" + email.charCodeAt(i) + ";";
      }
      output += encodedEmail;
    } else {
      output += email;
    }
    if (document.OBFUSCATOR.reverse.checked) {
      output += "</span>";
    }

    document.getElementById("output").value = document.OBFUSCATOR.link.checked ? "<a href=\"&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;" + (document.OBFUSCATOR.encode.checked ? encodedEmail : email) + "\">" + output + "</a>" : output;
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output").value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has room for improvement,

in top-bottom order:

- Your code is littered with DOM queries, I would suggest to group them all on top, they reduce comprehension speed
- Access elements through the form is considered old skool, always use getElementByID
- Adding a span around the email should be done in 1 go, it would be much cleaner
- You can determine the output in one shot, from the email address
- If continuing does not makes sense ( when email is blank ), return early, this will reduce [arrow coding](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

If you apply all this you should end up with something like this:

```
function obfuscateEmail( )
{
  var email = document.getElementById( 'email' ).value,
      encode = document.getElementById( 'encode' ).checked,
      reverse = document.getElementById( 'reverse' ).checked,
      link = document.getElementById( 'link' ).checked,
      output = document.getElementById( 'output' ),
      preview = document.getElementById('preview'),
      html = '',
      encodeEmail = '';

  if( !email ) {
    return alert('Please enter an email address.');
  }

  if( reverse ) {
    email = email.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
  if( encode ){
    for (var i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
      encodeEmail += '&#' + email.charCodeAt(i) + ';';
    }       
    email = encodeEmail;
  }

  html = reverse?( '<span class="email">' + email + '</span>' ):email;

  output.value = link ? "<a href=\"&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;" + email + "\">" + html + "</a>" : html;
  preview.innerHTML = output.value;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I think you forget to replace `output` with `html` here - `link ? "<a href=\"&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;" + email + "\">" + output + "</a>" : output`